# trace-bpfcc fails on 17.04

Tags: kernel, 17.04

When I try running `trace-bpfcc` installed from 17.04 repositories I get

```
chdir(/lib/modules/4.10.0-20-generic/source): No such file or directory
Failed to compile BPF module
```

I tried to install Linux sources from the repositories, but it did not solve the problem.

Is it a bug or I need to install some optional dependency?

Comment: Yes, it's a bug, you had raised one already https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bpfcc/+bug/1685503. If not, it should tell the correct setup (I couldn't find a ref for this). I could make only an adv step: (1) install `linux-source` (2) then extract it to `/lib/modules/4.10.0-20-generic/source` . But I get new issue similar to https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/issues/877 , I couldn't resolve yet, I even have `CONFIG_CGROUP_BPF=y` by default.